# Arranging N spheres in a unit cube

Tags: python, optimization, simulation, physics

I want to arrange N hard spheres inside a unit cube such that the volume density is eta.
I have a code with me but it is not that efficient.

```
def direct_disks_box(N, sigma):
    condition = False
    while condition == False:
        L = [[random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma), random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma), random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma)]]
        
        for k in range(1, N):
            a = [random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma), random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma), random.uniform(sigma, 1.0 - sigma)]
            min_dist = min(math.sqrt((a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2 + (a[2] - b[2]) ** 2) for b in L) 
            if min_dist < 2.0 * sigma: 
                condition = False
                break
            else:
                L.append(a)
                
                condition = True
    return L
```

If you look at the above code, the rejection rate is very high. Is there any way to reduce the rejection rate? A zero rejection rate would be great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you reject when the distance is less than twice your sigma and you want to reduce the times you reject. But your "L" array and your "a" array are generated using the same distribution (uniform, between the same limits) and therefore (without going into math) the probability distribution function (PDF) of your distance has a mean that is somewhat far from your "twice sigma" threshold and choosing minimum does not help.
In order to decrease your odds to reject you could make sure that your "a" array is generated using slightly loose limits. For example try the following:

```
threshold = -1.01 # changing "a" array distribution
a = [random.uniform(sigma*threshold, 1.0 - sigma*threshold), random.uniform(sigma*threshold, 1.0 - sigma*threshold),
             random.uniform(sigma*threshold, 1.0 - sigma*threshold)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. What I am trying to do is simulate N hard-spheres inside a unit cube such that the spheres won't overlap each other (thus less than twice the sigma condition). If I implement the threshold that you have suggested, won't some of the spheres be left outside the box?